# About unknown keys caught by 'unknown' in 'l3keys'

Tags: l3keys

Is there a way to catch with the key `unknown` all the unknown keys, including the keys of submodules?

For instance, in the following code, the unknown key `foo/bar` is *not* caught by the key `unknown`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { MyKeys } 
  { 
    one_key .bool_set:N = \l_my_bool , 
    unknown .code:n = \msg_error:nn { MyModule }{ Unknown~Key }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { MyModule } { Unknown~Key }
  { The~unknown~key~has~been~caught. }

\keys_set:nn { MyKeys } { foo / bar }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

If I define a key `unknown` in a submodule called `MyKeys / foo` with the following code:

```
\keys_define:nn { MyKeys / foo }
  { unknown .code:n = \msg_error:nn { MyModule }{ Unknown~Key } }
```

then the unknown key `foo/bar` is caught (by the key `unknown` of `MyKeys/foo`) but I would like to catch all the incorrect keys, including composed keys.